# Atheros AR2413 wireless not working after shutdown

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I am using a Ubuntu 11.04 on an Acer aspire 3680 laptop and my wifi is not working. I followed the below commands to install the madwifi driver:

```
sudo su
apt-get install subversion
cd /usr/src
svn checkout http://madwifi-project.org/svn/madwifi/trunk madwifi
tar cfvz madwifi.tgz 
cd madwifi
make && make install

echo "blacklist ath5k" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "ath_pci" >> /etc/modules

modprobe ath_pci

sudo reboot
```

After installation I am facing the same problem. My wifi wont work after I shutdown. Infact it didn't work after suspend but I rectified that problem by the following commands:

## Command 1:

```
sudo rmmod -f ath_pci

sudo rfkill unblock all

sudo modprobe ath_pci
```

along with the command SUSPEND_MODULES=ath_pci added to the /etc/pm/config.d/madwifi directory.

> - So if I suspend and then on my laptop the wifi loads well and doesn't create a problem.
> - But if I shutdown my laptop the wifi never loads again and eachtime I have to run a Ubuntu 9.04 live CD to load it. I did try adding the **Command 1** to the /etc/rc.local directory but still it doesn't work.
> - So my question is: What should I do in order to make my wireless work without having to run a live CD of ubuntu 9.04 everytime after shutdown?

Thanks.

Here are the outputs which one might need:

## Output 1

`chandru@chandru-acer:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7 Family) SATA IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8038 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 14)
0a:03.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR2413 802.11bg NIC (rev 01)
0a:09.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
0a:09.2 Mass storage controller: Texas Instruments 5-in-1 Multimedia Card Reader (SD/MMC/MS/MS PRO/xD)`

## Output 2:

`lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
wlan_tkip              17074  2 
binfmt_misc            13213  1 
parport_pc             32111  0 
ppdev                  12849  0 
snd_hda_codec_si3054    12924  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   255882  1 
joydev                 17322  0 
snd_atiixp_modem       18624  0 
snd_via82xx_modem      18305  0 
snd_intel8x0m          18493  0 
snd_ac97_codec        105614  3 snd_atiixp_modem,snd_via82xx_modem,snd_intel8x0m
snd_hda_intel          24113  2 
ac97_bus               12642  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_hda_codec          90901  3 snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
i915                  451053  3 
snd_hwdep              13274  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                80042  7 snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_atiixp_modem,snd_via82xx_modem,snd_intel8x0m,snd_ac97_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25269  1 snd_seq_midi
drm_kms_helper         40971  1 i915
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51291  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
pcmcia                 39671  0 
snd_timer              28659  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14110  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
drm                   184164  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
yenta_socket           27230  0 
tifm_7xx1              12898  0 
wlan_scan_sta          21945  1 
ath_rate_sample        17279  1 
pcmcia_rsrc            18292  1 yenta_socket
psmouse                73312  0 
tifm_core              15040  1 tifm_7xx1
snd                    55295  18 snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_atiixp_modem,snd_via82xx_modem,snd_intel8x0m,snd_ac97_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
serio_raw              12990  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13184  1 i915
soundcore              12600  1 snd
pcmcia_core            21505  3 pcmcia,yenta_socket,pcmcia_rsrc
video                  19112  1 i915
ath_pci               183044  0 
snd_page_alloc         14073  5 snd_atiixp_modem,snd_via82xx_modem,snd_intel8x0m,snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
wlan                  224640  5 wlan_tkip,wlan_scan_sta,ath_rate_sample,ath_pci
ath_hal               398701  3 ath_rate_sample,ath_pci
lp                     13349  0 
parport                36746  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usbhid                 41704  0 
hid                    77084  1 usbhid
sky2                   49172  0`

## Output 3

`root@chandru-acer:~# lshw -C network
PCI (sysfs)

  *-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8038 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 14
       serial: 00:16:36:fb:aa:64
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.28 firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:43 memory:44000000-44003fff ioport:2000(size=256)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR2413 802.11bg NIC
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:03.0
       logical name: wifi0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:19:7d:d3:0c:fd
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list logical ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath_pci ip=192.168.1.6 latency=96 maxlatency=28 mingnt=10 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11g
       resources: irq:18 memory:d0000000-d000ffff`

## Output 4

`root@chandru-acer:~# lsmod | grep ath_pci
ath_pci               183044  0 
wlan                  224640  5 wlan_tkip,wlan_scan_sta,ath_rate_sample,ath_pci
ath_hal               398701  3 ath_rate_sample,ath_pci`

Comment: Is /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath-pci.conf still in place? Before you simply remove it, I suggest you read it. "# For some Atheros 5K RF MACs, the madwifi driver loads buts fails to
# correctly initialize the hardware, leaving it in a state from
# which ath5k cannot recover...."

Comment: @chili555 so what are you suggesting me to do. I am deeply frustrated with this problem. Yes that blacklist-ath-pic.conf still in place.

Comment: Of course, if I knew the answer, I'd just answer. I can only suggest a few experiments. I'd move the blacklist file aside, but not remove it altogether so you can restore it if needed: sudo mv /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath-pci.conf  ~  That will move the file to you user directory and it will not have any effect on the system or loaded modules; in other words, you won't simultaneously blacklist and load ath-pci. Then I'd reboot and see if things changed or improved.

Comment: @chili555: Nope, I am sorry that doesn't work. :(

Comment: When you boot and it doesn't work, what does dmesg say? dmesg | grep ath. Why did you decide to try ath_pci instead of ath5k?